# Trouble calling images with a php instance

Tags: php, html, css, image

I am currently building a gallery using some very basic php - namely the inclusion of:

```
<?php include("page.php"); ?>
```

but I'm running into an issue calling images.

To explain the situation, I am building a php page for each item of artwork I want displayed and instead of building 30+ additional pages in the root folder I have created a sub-folder  (in this case '/art/' ) where all of the artwork pages will live. Linking to them is easy enough but when I go to view the pages items I am calling in such as header.php or footer.php don't appear.
Example:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```

Now, simply adding '../' resolves this issue and the header, footer and additional php items I need are imported.

```
<?php include("../header.php"); ?>
```

Unfortunately the images are not - all I get in their place is the default missing/broken image icon. Of course if I go into the headr.php page and add the '../' to each image I am calling in then it works great in the php files in the /art/ folder but then I get the exact same broken icons when I go to any pages in the root directory such as index.php.

The conclusion I am at is that while adding ../ does point the page inside the /art/ folder to look in the previous directory it is still trying to locate images from an image folder within the /art/ folder and not the /images/ folder in the root folder. I could easily just make a copy of the contents of the images folder and place it within the the /art/ folder but that seems redundant.

Is there a better, preferred solution to tell the php include where to look for the images? Or is it best to just house all php pages in the same root folder?

Comment: Are you just rendering different images using each include? Wouldn't it be easier & simpler to use for example the <img> html tag for each image? You would define each image as <img src="/path/to/image.png">,  so no matter where you render this from, it will always link the image as example.com/path/to/image.png

Comment: Can you access the directory from the full url? Surely you can just place this in, so $imgfolder = http://example.com/images/

Comment: Your file references inside the HTML should be absolute, i.e. start with `/`; this way it won't matter from which path they are referenced.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you are recommending that I could either make the image paths in the header.php page to read 'example.com/images/image.jpg' instead of simply 'images.image.jpg' or to add '$imgfolder = example.com/images;' inside of my       <?php include("../footer.php"); ?> correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I had this one before :),

It's an issue because when you import the file php just pasts
the file contents in the new file so the relative pathing is
then made from there.

TL;DR
Use dirname(**FILE**).'/'.(..) as your path's instead.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: The description you gave made perfect sense, but can you elaborate on (ironically) the TL;DR portion? I didn't quite follow

Comment: Thanks, between your reply and the comment by Jack (above) I think I see the problem and what you meant.